# Jest mock not working with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am using `@testing-library/react` for testing UI components. Cannot get jest mock working.

It seems it cannot mock the implementation of the exported function `getDomElement` but actual implementation is called.

Implementation of Table.test.js

```
describe('Table', () => {
  jest.mock('../../../../commonHelpers/getDomElement.js', () => {});

  it('it renders columns', () => {
    render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={data}         
        />
      </ThemeProvider>,
    );
  })
})
```

Implementation of Table.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {
  useTable,
  useSortBy,
  useBlockLayout,
  useResizeColumns,
  usePagination,
} from 'react-table';

import { TableStyled as Table, TableContainer } from './styled';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import Head from './Head';
import Body from './Body';
import TableContext from './TableContext';

const Table = ({
  columns,
  data,
  onChangeSort,
  fetchData,
  pageCount: calculatedPageCount,
  initialPageSize,
}) => {
  const tableInstance = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      manualSortBy: true,
      disableSortRemove: false,
      manualPagination: true,
      pageCount: calculatedPageCount,
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: initialPageSize },
    },
    useSortBy,
    useBlockLayout,
    useResizeColumns,
    usePagination,
  );

  const {
    getTableProps,
    state: { pageIndex, pageSize },
  } = tableInstance;


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData({ pageIndex, pageSize });
  }, [fetchData, pageIndex, pageSize]);

  return (
    <TableContext.Provider value={tableInstance}>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table {...getTableProps()}>
          <Head onChangeSort={onChangeSort} />
          <Body />
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <Pagination />
    </TableContext.Provider>
  );
};

Table.propTypes = {
  columns: PropTypes.array,
  data: PropTypes.array,
  onChangeSort: PropTypes.func,
  fetchData: PropTypes.func,
  pageCount: PropTypes.number,
  initialPageSize: PropTypes.number,
};

export default Table;
```

Implementation of getDomElement.js which returns the dom element by given id.

```
export default function getDomElement(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Test results in:

`const width = getDomElement('project-list').clientWidth;`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null`

Comment: Please include some more info.

Comment: Added `Table` and `getDomElement` implementations.

Comment: @RootNode I'm facing the same issue. My `jest.mock` only works when it is in jestsetup.js. When I move the same to a test file it doesn't work. It only started to happen when I moved to `@testing-library/react`

Answer (score 4):

Doing following two thing, got it working for me.

1. Adding `__esModule:true` fixed this issue for me.

   `jest.mock('module',()=>({ __esModule: true, default: jest.fn() }));`
2. Moving the mocking part before the describe. (Just after the imports.)

   //moving it to before the describe ->
   `jest.mock(...); describe('', ...);`

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import * as myModule from '../../../../commonHelpers/getDomElement';
describe('Table', () => {
  jest.spyOn(myModule, "getDomElement").mockImplementation(() => {});
  it('it renders columns', () => {
    render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={data}         
        />
      </ThemeProvider>,
    );
  })
})
```

Comment: For some reason having the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of null`

Comment: Could you add the code for `getDomElement` and `Table`?

Comment: Sure, `getDomElement` and `Table` implementations have now been added.

Comment: But where are you using `getDomElement`? In `ThemeProvider`? If so, please add the code for it too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was 3 years ago, but if anyone is still having the same problem (with Typescript) I was able to fix it.

So the problem happens when you add `import '@testing-library/react-native/extend-expect';` to setupJest file along with a jest.mock.

[According to the documentation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/jest-matchers#setup), you can use `setupFilesAfterEnv` as an alternative for the import.
Add the bellow to your package.json:

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": ["@testing-library/react-native/extend-expect"]
```

Now it'll work but Typescript is still complaining about some expect functions. Now we'll trick typescript into thinking everything is ok.

Create a second file called `setupTestingLibrary.ts` and add the import there. Typescript will think this file is being used and will read the types.

In my case, the `setupJest.ts` file is in root directory. You should create the second file in the same directory as setupJest, but if that doesn't work try creating both at root dir.

Hope it helps.